# sonar ant build.xml file for running default Sun checks on Java project

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I am a beginner to SONAR , i just need a help for a sample ant build file for running my java project name 'Hello World' with SONAR 's default Sun checks Quality profile .I have not found anywhere any proper ant guide for sonar. I am using SONAR 2.10 .

Please help me in starting with SONAR .

```
<project name="Example" default="Sonar" basedir=".">
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
 <classpath path="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\ant\lib\sonar-ant-task-1.0.jar" />
</taskdef>
<!-- Out-of-the-box those parameters are optional -->
<property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/sonar" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="root" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="root" />
<!-- Additional Sonar configuration (PMD need 1.5 when using annotations)-->
<property name="sonar.java.source" value="1.5"/>
<property name="sonar.java.target" value="1.5"/>
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="Example"/>
<property name="sonar.binaries" value="C:\Documents and   Settings\tausif\Feature2\Example\bin"/>
 <!-- SERVER ON A REMOTE HOST -->
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://localhost:8080/sonar" />
<target name="Sonar">
<!-- The workDir directory is used by Sonar to store temporary files -->
<sonar:sonar workDir="C:\Documents and Settings\tausif\Feature2\Sonar" key="com.example:example"  xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant" >
  <!-- source directories (required) -->
  <sources>
    <path location="C:\Documents and Settings\tausif\Feature2\Example" />
  </sources>
</sonar:sonar>
</target>
</project>
```

The above two answers were realy helpful for me to create this xml file .
This is my sample build.xml . Can you please check what i am missing in it?
I have made Sun checks as default.My project name is Example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [this](http://www.sonarsource.org/sonar-2-6-adds-continuous-inspection-support-for-ant-community/) (*Sonar 2.6: Adds Continuous Inspection Support for Ant Community*)  or [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task+1.0) (*Analyse with Ant Task 1.0*) documentation helpful.

Comment: Thanks , but i have gone through this and all over google and it was not much helpful for me to understand how to run Sun checks for my Hello word project. Any sample build.xml for Sun check will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Md Tausif Warsi make sun checks the default quality profile in your server. Then everything will be run with this profile. Or use the paramate sonar.profile which is defined here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Advanced+parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below ant script which is specific to the sonar.
You can add it in your build.xml.
Below is the script with the details

```
<!-- Here you need to set the path which contains sonar specific jars required for ant  e.g. path which contains sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar -->
<path id="sonar.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/sonar" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>

<!-- This taskdef represents your ant lib for sonar you have to specify jar location along with jar name in class path no need to change the uri and resource-->
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="${basedir}\sonar\sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar" />
</taskdef>

<!-- This is the target we use to run sonar "depends" property is optional -->
<target name="sonar" depends="clean, compile">
            <!-- specify your build version -->  
    <property name="build.version" value="0.0.0.1-Sonar"/>

            <!-- specify your organization name its optional --> 
    <property name="mysonar.organizationName" value="XYZ"/>

            <!-- specify your project Name --> 
    <property name="sonar.projectName" value="${project.name}" />

            <!-- database url which is used by the sonar -->
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://<IP>:<Port>/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" />

            <!-- Driver name-->
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

            <!-- database user name --> 
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="test" />

            <!-- database password -->
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="test" />

            <!-- url on which sonar is running-->
    <property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://<IP>:<Port>" />

             <!-- project key -->
     <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="${mysonar.organizationName}:${sonar.projectName}" />

             <!-- project version--> 
     <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />

            <!-- location source files --> 
    <property name="sonar.sources" value="${src.home}/main/java" /> 

            <!-- location of binaries after compilation--> 
    <property name="sonar.binaries" value="${basedir}/output"/>

            <!-- location of sonar library-->  
    <sonar:sonar xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">

    </sonar:sonar>
</target>
```

Note: Make sure that location you specify are correct you can give absolute path as well.

Comment: You mentioned in commented line , mySonar.organizationName is **optional** then why you use it in sonar.projectkey on value attribute. Can you please tell me why you use projectkey in  it? what you mean in organizationname. Sonar integration.